# setTimeout is not working correctly inside "for loop"

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, iteration, settimeout

Now of course, code only does what you make it do.

But i'm confused why in the following code:

```
var a = {
    0: "Hi",
    1: "Bye"
}

for (var b in a) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(b);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Instead of consoling "0" and then "1"

I just get "1" twice.

I'm not sure why that happens. I need a setup like that for a script I am making but I also get the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is because your usage of closure is wrong.

In this case you are using the closure variable `b` inside the `setTimeout` callback, but the value of the variable `b` is not looked up until the callback is executed, by then the value of updated to the last value in the object.

One of the solution in such case is the create a local closure as given below

```
for (var b in a) {
    (function(c){
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(c);
        }, 1000);
    })(b)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NxqHg/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way too

```
for (var b in a) {
    setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, b), 1000);
}
```

Or like this

```
for (var b in a) {
    setTimeout(function(c) {
        console.log(c)
    }.bind(null, b), 1000);
}
```

Or even like this

```
// compatibility varies
for (var b in a) {
    setTimeout(function(c) {
        console.log(c)
    }, 1000, b);
}
```

Comment: More like `setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, b)`

Comment: @Musa, `console.log.bind(null, b)` works in this scenario too. `console.log` does not need its own context to work.

Comment: So you don't get `Illegal Invocation`?

Comment: @Musa, hmm, in `node-0.10.12` it works with `null`, but in browser it looks like it requires `console`. Thanks for catching this dissimilarity. I only do node work so I never noticed :)